# Chartjs 3.2 problem with setting whole numbers for Y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a lot of experience with chart.js but their new version breaks a lot of stuff and it has a lot of bugs and problems.

I want my line chart y axis to have integer numbers lets say: [0, 1, 2, 3...] instead I get [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5...]

What I have tried

```js
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    type: 'linear', 
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      stepSize: 1, // DOES NOT WORK, PROBABLY DEPRECATED IN V3
      precision: 1, // DOES NOT DO ANYTHING
      callback: function (value) { console.log(value)} // CALLBACK DOES NOT        EVEN RUN...
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation is just awful and does not help with any of this. In the documentation they show a lot of options that you can use, but skip out on how to use them..

Comment: Can you provide a MRE (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The problem might lie in the surrounding code. Also a link to the relevant documentation might help.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the intended behavior with `react-chartjs-2@4.1.0` and `chart.js@3.7.1` with this:

```
scales: {
    y: {
        type: 'linear' as const, // magic
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
        },
    },
},
```

setting the type as const is the trick.
I was initially trying it the way you did until I found this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, not a solution
I downgraded my react-chartjs-2 wrapper to 2.9.0 and installed chart.js dependecy version 2.5.0 this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem (at least regarding the fractional values) is 'precision: 1'. If you do not want to have the decimal values, it should be 'precision: 0'.